# dimiss two loaded view controllers with action of button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a situation where two view controllers are loaded on top of the initial view controller, and when the third view controller is loaded I would like to dismiss the two view controllers for the action of a button on the third view controller.  Right now the button is only dismissing one view controller with the following code,

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {

[serial close];

if([self.view isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerCreate class]] ) {


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

I don't need to dismiss two view controllers every time, just when this particular situation presents itself.

For clarity sake, there is a button in the first view controller which presents the second view controller when pressed, then when the second view controller is loaded, there is a button when pressed presents the third view controller.

Comment: I’m pretty sure your condition is never getting hit. `self.view` is going to be a `UIView` subclass, and I’m guessing `ViewControllerCreate` is a `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: yes sir, ViewControllerCreate is a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Right, so the expression in your conditional will never evaluate to `YES`, so `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is only getting called once. Without checking, however, I don’t even know whether a modal view controller *can* present *another* modal view controller.

Comment: That's what I'm doing to present the view controllers, I'm using modal transitions.  I'm sure it's not the proper way to do things, but that's how I have been doing it :/

Comment: Is the first view controller presenting both the second and third, or is the first presenting the second, and then the second is presenting the third?

Comment: Yes, the first view controller has a button that presents the second view controller, and the second view controller has a button that presents the third view controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34872/discussion-between-zev-eisenberg-and-chris)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have the desired behavior using the following code,

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {

    [serial close];

    if([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerCreate class]] ) {

        [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` which would allow you to chain multiple dismisses. Dismiss the first, pass in a completion to check for the necessary requirements to dismiss the second, etc.